# Communicating between WP 7 Application deployed on a emulator and a desktop application

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, localhost, tcpclient

Currently I have a server which uses the `TcpListener` class to communicate with clients.
I have to test the communication between the Windows Phone client app and the server.

The problem is while developing my server is listening the `IPAdress.Loopback` (localhost) on my machine.

Is there any way to create connection to the server from the emulator, so I can test anything.

Comment: hi,my requirement is same as yours, I had a server which uses the TCpListener and i am accepting client like this TcpClient tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient().I want to connect to this server through Tcp sockets & in my windows phone app using managed code i am trying to open the connection. But i got a socket error of "connection refused".How did you connect your server tcp listener. Have you used Tcp socket if so can you help me.I tried a lot but could not.. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Well if I remember rightly you need to setup a port on your TCPListener, if that port is the same as the port VS is listening on then we will have a problem, the article below explains in good detail how to set up proper connections using TCPListener

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx

you could just set up a laptop with your server/client on and have your emulator connect to the private network addess of that machine then you can test otherwise I would normally fire up a Virtual Machine on my Desktop and connect to it for testing Server/client stuff